# @AfterMethod method not executed when using invocationTimeOut and invocationCount > 2 (TestNG 6.9 -> 6.10)

Tags: java, testng

I want my test retry 5 times and not longer than x minutes. After the last invocation, it will invoke mergeReport method in @Aftermethod. Here my example code:

```
@Test(priority = 1, invocationCount = 5, invocationTimeOut = 6000, expectedExceptions = ThreadTimeoutException.class)
public void test() throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

@AfterMethod(lastTimeOnly = true, alwaysRun = true)
public void mergeReport(ITestResult result) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Report");
}
```

Test result will be empty. But when I change invocationCount to 2, the test result will be:

```
Report
```

I search through the internet and found a similar issue from 2014 but it still have no answer: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/325

Has anyone met this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure 325 is a similar issue. Could you open a new one and provide a full runnable project there?

Comment: I fixed this issue by using TestListenerAdapter and IInvokedMethodListener. If the test timeout before it reaches the invocationCount = 5, my custom listener will set it to 5 and the after method will be triggered. `while (iTestResult.getMethod().getCurrentInvocationCount() < iTestResult.getMethod().getTotalInvocationCount()) {
            iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().incrementCurrentInvocationCount();
        }`

Answer (score 0):

*Have you tried with timeOut instead of invocationTimeout?*

```
@Test(priority = 1, invocationCount = 5, invocationTimeout= 20000, expectedExceptions = ThreadTimeoutException.class)
public void test() throws Exception {
    while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

From testng doc:

> invocationTimeOut-->  The maximum number of milliseconds this test
>   should take for the ***cumulated*** time of all the invocationcounts. This
>   attribute will be ignored if invocationCount is not specified.
>
> timeOut   --> The maximum number of milliseconds this test should take.

I think you are after timeOut for what you want!

Then again, you mention at your decription that you want to run for a X number of minutes. And the key word is *'cumulated '*. By the way 6000 milliseconds is 6 seconds, so you need 360000 for 6 minutes for example (silly, I know but maybe that is why you don't get the desired effect).

> Hence, my guess will be that your program spawns 'Report' when you set
>   invocation to 2; only because it has enough time to complete (i.e.
>   perform 2 invocations, or call it twice if you prefer within the 6
>   seconds margin). When you set it to 5 it just does not have enough
>   time to complete! :)

In order to fix whether try the timeOut parameter or if you prefer invocationTimeOut then set it to something higher so your test can complete  within  the desired time-frame. Judging from your successful example setting **invocationTimeOut =20000** should suffice ;)

Best of luck!

Comment: I tried. If I use timeOut instead of invocationTimeOut, the after method will be triggered every invocation even I set _lastTimeOnly = true_.

Comment: Okay, updated my answer based on your feedback @Chip Li. Have you also tried increasing the actual invocationTimeout=20000?

Comment: Yes I did. I reduce invocationTimeout to 6000 to reproduce the issue.

Comment: So I suppose increasing invocation count fixed your issue (or not?) I am confused :)

Comment: I fixed this issue by using TestListenerAdapter and IInvokedMethodListener. If the test timeout before it reaches the invocationCount = 5, my custom listener will set it to 5 and the after method will be triggered. while (iTestResult.getMethod().getCurrentInvocationCount() < iTestResult.getMethod().getTotalInvocationCount()) { iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().incrementCurrentInvocationCou‌​nt(); }